# Spring Component scanned bean not accessable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a UserDetailsService class annotated with @Service. I also have DAO classes annonated which are autowiring and working fine within my controllers.

The problem is when I want to wire up the UserDetailsService bean within my security-context.xml. Spring is unable to find the bean. Is it because my component-scan is in my controllers.xml file and out of the scope of my security configuration?

xml config file layout as so :

web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
              /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
              /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

servlet-context.xml :

```
...
<beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />
...
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333390/service-are-constructed-twice/4335438#4335438

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll need to add the component scan to both contexts, it's not enough to do it in just one.