# How to import Java-config class into XML-config so that both contexts have beans?

Tags: spring, configuration

I have a project where I need to bootstrap @Configuration java-config classes into the XML configuration.

To do that, I'm reading that I also need to include the following bean definition (along with the bean definitions of the classes annotated with @Configuration).

```
<bean class="org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor" />
```

But, I end up receiving the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor
```

I have to assume I'm missing a jar somewhere, but my various web searches hasn't resulted in an answer yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**EDIT**:  Evidently, I was reading old documentation, which is no longer current.  Let me back up.  My project contains older XML-based configuration.  The newer code is all using 'Java-config'.  With that said, the contexts are apparently completely separate.  I'd like to 'import' a java-config class into the XML configuration, so that both contexts have those particular beans.  Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This actually ended up being fairly simple.  To get a Java-config bean definition into the xml-config, simply define the Java-config class as a bean within the XML-config.  There are no extra jars necessary.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeJavaConfig {

    @bean
    ... [bean definition]
}
```

inside the XML-config, you define this class as a bean.

```
<!-- needed to pick up the annotated java-config -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Importing java-config class, which are annotated with @Configuration -->
<bean name="SomeJavaConfig" class="[fully qualified path].SomeJavaConfig" />
```

The XML-config, which may be part of a different context, now has all the bean definitions defined within the JavaConfig class.

**UPDATED** - to included Alan Franzoni's comment below in the answer.

Comment: Sidenote: <context:annotation-config/> must exist in your XML config as well, otherwise your javaconfig won't be included.

Comment: if you already define ConfigurationPostProcessor in your XML config,<context:annotation-config/> not needed!

Comment: <context:annotation-config/> tag just added all the springs PostProcessors for you.

Comment: can we use <import resource="..."/> as we do for another xml config file.

Comment: Is the forward slash intentional?

Comment: @thenaglecode- no... that was probably a typo (when I was copy/pasting from a real-world example and editing for this post). The value of the bean name can be whatever you want it to be -I generally leave them the name of the class (unless there's some other reason to change it)

Comment: Please add the hint of Alan Franzoni to you answer - this was helpful.

Comment: There is no need for `<context:annotation-config/>` - and it might pickup all available Configurations. I'm working with profiles, thus I define one Configuration bean per profile and it is working. If you really need scanning, use the ComponentScan annotation at your Config class.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively to `annotation-config` you can use `component-scan`. Then you do not have to include the Configuration Bean in XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="[fully qualified package path]" />
```

See [Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Should be in:

```
spring-javaconfig-<version>.jar
```

Comment: Evidently, the spring-javaconfig jar was decomissioned.  It was supposed to be migrated into Spring Core in version 3.0.