# Spring XML and java configuration together

Tags: java, spring

I have a project with XML based spring configuration and want to define some new beans but in java class based configuration.

How to implement  this so that i can also refer beans of java configuration in my XML config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import your xml config into java configuration, like so:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:pl/rav/springtest/resources/app.xml")
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name="myMessageService")
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return new MessageServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

When you want to refer from xml to the bean you just point to its name:

```
<property name="msgSrv">
    <ref bean="myMessageService"/>
</property>
```

Then use ApplicationContext based on your java configuration.

```
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

As you started with xml config, you may be interested in other way around (importing java config into xml config) which I think was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254779/how-to-import-java-config-class-into-xml-config-so-that-both-contexts-have-beans)