# Java Spring Framework JavaConfig in XML configuration

Tags: xml, spring, spring-bean

This question has been asked earlier at below thread but my code is still not working.
[please click for the earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254779/how-to-import-java-config-class-into-xml-config-so-that-both-contexts-have-beans)

This is the case of mixed wiring in Spring Framework.
I have a spring wiring where I am trying to invoke javaconfig beans from xml and then invoking xml via application context but still getting error.

Code details are below:

**beanconfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

        <bean class="org.spring.wiring.javabasd.appcontextxml.JavaConfig">
        </bean>     
</beans>
```

**JavaConfig** class

```
package org.spring.wiring.javabasd.appcontextxml;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    @Configuration
    class JavaConfig {
        @Bean
        public Shape xyz(){ 
            return new Sphere();        
        }

        @Bean
        public Details abc(){       
            return new Details(xyz());
        }
    }
```

**XMLbased Application Context Call**

```
package org.spring.wiring.javabasd.appcontextxml;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:org/spring/wiring/javabasd/appcontextxml/beanconfig.xml");
        Details gg = context.getBean(Details.class);

        gg.getVolume();
        context.close();
        }
}
```

Below is the error I get when I run it.

```
Feb 21, 2017 9:08:25 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b1a58a3: startup date [Tue Feb 21 21:08:25 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 21, 2017 9:08:25 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/spring/wiring/javabasd/appcontextxml/beanconfig.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.spring.wiring.javabasd.appcontextxml.Details] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1088)
    at org.spring.wiring.javabasd.appcontextxml.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

> Looks like JavaConfig call is being made but 'Details' and 'Shape' beans are not getting created.
>   Please help and let me know if codes of other classes are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `<context:annotation-config/>` in your beanconfig.xml. Because while `<context:annotation-config/>` is switched on, the container will recognize the @Configuration annotation and process the @Bean methods declared in AppConfig properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config/>

        <bean class="org.spring.wiring.javabasd.appcontextxml.JavaConfig">
        </bean>     
</beans>
```