# Spring CrudRepository is null for @Autowired member variable

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring JPA. I am trying to use hibernate + Spring JPA. For this I created below repository

```
package com.raptorservice.da.dal;

import com.raptorservice.da.objects.ClientDO;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<ClientDO, String> {    
}
```

Below is my spring-ws-servlet.xml where i browse through my packages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                        ">

    <!--  ****************************** BASIC CONFIGURATION ******************************************** -->
    <!-- Enable annotations for end points -->
    <sws:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="getpointsbean" class="com.raptorservice.endpoints.GetPointsEndpoint">
    </bean>

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="points" portTypeName="Points" locationUri="/points/" targetNamespace="http://sailin.com/schemas">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/xsd/points.xsd" />
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

    <!--  Configure JAXB to marshal and un-marshal requests -->
    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="jaxbMarshaller"  contextPath="com.raptorservice.generated" />



    <!-- ******************************* PERSISTANCE CONFIGURATION ****************************************** -->
    <!--  JPA Repositories -->
<jpa:repositories  base-package="com.raptorservice.da.dal" /> 



    <!--  Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testservice" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="./WEB-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
     </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<!--        <property name="configLocation"> -->
<!--            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value> -->
<!--        </property> -->
<!--        <property name="configurationClass"> -->
<!--            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value> -->
<!--        </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>



 </beans>
```

I do have a valid persistence.xml file too under WEB-INF.

I am trying to use the ClientRepository in my webservice (@Endpoint) as below

```
package com.raptorservice.endpoints;


@Endpoint
public class GetPointsEndpoint {    

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

@PayloadRoot(localPart="getPointsForClientAndCustomerRequest", namespace="http://sailin.com/schemas")
    @ResponsePayload()
    public GetPointsForClientAndCustomerResponse getPointsForClientAndCustomerRequest(@RequestPayload GetPointsForClientAndCustomerRequest getpointsRequest) throws Exception
    {
        GetPointsForClientAndCustomerResponse resp = new GetPointsForClientAndCustomerResponse();
        ResultCode resCode = new ResultCode();

        try
        {
        ClientDO client = new ClientDO();
        client.setName("Test1");
        client.setClientId("test111");
        clientRepository.save(client);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          System.out.println(ex);
        }


        resCode.setDescription("pass");
        resCode.setCode(BigInteger.valueOf(5));
        resp.setResultCode(resCode);
        return resp;
    }
```

But the clientRepository is always null. What am I missing? Why is clientRepository not being auto wired?

I checked the logs and nothing obvious. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `<context:annotation-config/>` is missing, this annotation is required to register a [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) instance in the application context.

[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) is also implicitly registered in the app context if you have used 
`<context:component-scan ...>` annotation in its xml configuration.

See [Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan)

Typically if the field value is null and no exception occurs it means that either the object is not a Spring bean(instantiated somewhere else), or that it's not post processed by the IoC container(maybe the post processor was registered in [another context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring) ).

As the beans are eagerly initialized singletons and `@Autowired` annotation has **required** attribute set to true by default, Spring will most likely throw an exception during the container initialization if the bean is processed at all.

Comment: Hi Boris, Thanks for the response.  After adding <context:annotation-config/> i see that it atleast tried injecting my member variable. However it failed complaining that one of the bean is not registered. I guess I have to do study the component-scan for that. But thanks for the tip and link.