# SpringAOP, load-time-weaver, strange behavior

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

in this moment i am facing one problem and really dont know what i am doing wrong. I am coding logging for my webservice using Spring framework and AOP in @AspectJ style. I got two bundles - background and frontend. In background bundle I have LogAspect, which look like this:

```
@Aspect
public class LogAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(logMethod)")
    public void logMethodAnnotated(LogMethod logMethod){}

    @Before("logMethodAnnotated(logMethod)")
    public void beforeLogMethodAnnotated(JoinPoint jp){
        //actions
    }

    @After("logMethodAnnotated(logMethod)")
    public void afterLogMethodAnnotated(JoinPoint jp){
        //actions   
    }
}
```

and META-INF/spring/background-osgi.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="simon.background"/>

<context:load-time-weaver />
```

and also META-INF/aop.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>

    <weaver>

        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="simon.background.*"/>
        <include within="simon.frontend.controller.*"/>

    </weaver>

    <aspects>

        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->        
        <aspect name="simon.background.log.LogAspect"/>

    </aspects>

  </aspectj>
```

In frontend bundle I've just put into aplicationContext.xml `<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" />`. But the code is acting very strange. I found out, that there is some problem, when I put into my advice methods JoinPoint as argument. (I mean, when I got advice methods without arguments, so there were no JoinPoin in method header, everything has been working fine and advices has been running before and after @LogMethod (my annotation, which I use to say, that i want to log this method) annotated methods). But now it is working like this:
- when I start server and so that the bundles are deployed for the first time, then the advices are run just for methods, they are @LogMethod annotated and belongs to background bundle, but not for annotated methods in frontend.controller.
- and in addition, when I have done some changes in one of my controllers, saved it and deployed just frontend bundle, then when I run @LogMethod annotated method, I got this error:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "simon.background.log.LogAspect.afterLogMethodAnnotated(Lorg/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint;)V" the class loader (instance of com/springsource/kernel/userregion/internal/equinox/KernelBundleClassLoader) of the current class, simon/frontend/controller/HuhController, and the class loader (instance of com/springsource/kernel/userregion/internal/equinox/KernelBundleClassLoader) for resolved class, simon/background/log/LogAspect, have different Class objects for the type /aspectj/lang/JoinPoint;)V used in the signature

Any ideas what is going on and how can i fix it, so my program will be able to run advices correctly?

One additional note, it could maybe help: When I run this in Debug mode with advices without JoinPoint argument, I realized, that both advices were running twice for one method.

Answer (score 0):

On running twice, could it be because you are using both  and 
 at the same time? [Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan)

Answer (score 0):

Your pointcut has been triggered twice because your expression only constraints annotation type. When a method is called, `call()` and `execution()` are both match this expression so.

You can use `@annotation(xxx) && execution(* *(..))` on your point cut to restrict the condition on execution only.