# Chain reaction in Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Does it matter in which order the Spring resolves annotated beans defined in a Spring definition file as follows :

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.for.jms"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.for.lookup"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.for.persistence"/>
```

Comment: I found a brilliant answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456501/259889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter. They will all be beans and the bean creation cycle should sort out the needed creation order.