# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.hadoop.hive.HiveOperations]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hadoop, hive

My application is combination of hadoop and rest service with spring framework. My aim is to provide results from hive table on request. But when I run application, after completion of mapreduce and hive job I get following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logsRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void hello.logsRepository.logsRepositoryC(org.springframework.data.hadoop.hive.HiveOperations); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.hadoop.hive.HiveOperations] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:616)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:877)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:866)
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:63)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void hello.logsRepository.logsRepositoryC(org.springframework.data.hadoop.hive.HiveOperations); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.hadoop.hive.HiveOperations] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.hadoop.hive.HiveOperations] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
        ... 24 more
```

My code:

application.java

```
@ComponentScan 
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    private static AbstractApplicationContext ctx;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/hadoop-context.xml");
      // shut down the context cleanly along with the VM
      ctx.registerShutdownHook();

        HiveTemplate template = ctx.getBean(HiveTemplate.class);
        log.info(template.query("show tables;"));

        logsRepository repository = ctx.getBean(logsRepository.class);
        repository.processLogFile("/home/hduser/yarn/hive_data");

        log.info("Count of password entries = " + repository.count());

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); 
    }   

}
```

logsRepository.java

```
@Repository
public class logsRepository implements logsRepo {

    private String tableName = "getlogs";


    private HiveOperations hiveOperations;

    @Autowired
    public void logsRepositoryC (HiveOperations hiveOperations) {
        this.hiveOperations = hiveOperations;
    }

    @Override
    public Long count() {
        return hiveOperations.queryForLong("select count(*) from " + tableName);
    }

    @Override
    public void processLogFile(String inputFile) {
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("inputFile", inputFile);
        hiveOperations.query("classpath:logs-analysis.hql", parameters);

    }
}
```

hadoop-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

        <context:property-placeholder location="hadoop.properties,hive.properties" />

        <context:component-scan base-package="hello" />

        <hdp:configuration>
            fs.defaultFS=${hd.fs}
            yarn.resourcemanager.address=${hd.rm}
            mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
            mapred.job.tracker=${hd.jt}
        </hdp:configuration>

        <hdp:script id="setupScript" location="copy-files.groovy">
          <hdp:property name="localSourceFile" value="${localSourceFile}"/>
          <hdp:property name="inputDir" value="${inputDir}"/>
          <hdp:property name="outputDir" value="${outputDir}"/>
        </hdp:script>

        <hdp:script id="setupfile" location="copy-to-local.groovy">
          <hdp:property name="outputDir" value="${outputDir}"/>
        </hdp:script>

        <hdp:job id="getlogsJob" 
            input-path="${inputDir}" 
            output-path="${outputDir}" 
            libs="${LIB_DIR}/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar" 
            mapper="hello.GetLogs.Map" 
            reducer="hello.GetLogs.Reduce" />

        <hdp:hive-client-factory host="${hive.host}" port="${hive.port}"/>  

        <hdp:hive-template id="hiveTemplate" hive-client-factory-ref="hiveClientFactory" />     

        <hdp:hive-runner id="hiveRunner" hive-client-factory-ref="hiveClientFactory" run-at-startup="false" pre-action="hdfsScript">
            <hdp:script location="logs-analysis.hql">
            </hdp:script>
        </hdp:hive-runner>

        <hdp:script id="hdfsScript" language="groovy" location="set-hive-permissions.groovy"/> 

        <hdp:job-runner id="runner" run-at-startup="true" pre-action="setupScript,hdfsScript" post-action="setupfile,hiveRunner"  job-ref="getlogsJob" /> 
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC3</version>
    </parent>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>hadoop22</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.hadoop.version>2.0.0.M5-hadoop22</spring.hadoop.version>
                <hadoop.version>2.2.0</hadoop.version>
                <hive.version>0.10.0</hive.version>
                <hadoop.version.generic>2.0.0-cdh4.1.3</hadoop.version.generic>
                <hadoop.version.mr1>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3</hadoop.version.mr1>
                <hadoop.examples>hadoop-mapreduce-examples</hadoop.examples>
                <mapreduce.framework>yarn</mapreduce.framework>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
                    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>phd1</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.hadoop.version>1.0.2.RELEASE-phd1</spring.hadoop.version>
                <hadoop.version>2.0.5-alpha-gphd-2.1.0.0</hadoop.version>
                <hadoop.examples>hadoop-mapreduce-examples</hadoop.examples>
                <mapreduce.framework>yarn</mapreduce.framework>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
                    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>config</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <copy todir="target/appassembler/data">
                                            <fileset dir="data"/>
                                        </copy>
                                        <copy todir="target/appassembler/etc">
                                            <fileset dir="etc/phd1"/>
                                        </copy>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>${java.version}</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${spring.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${spring.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${spring.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-builtins</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-shims</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <!-- <version>2.3.2</version> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                    <configurationSourceDirectory>src/main/config</configurationSourceDirectory>
                    <copyConfigurationDirectory>true</copyConfigurationDirectory>
                    <extraJvmArguments>-Dmr.fw=${mapreduce.framework}</extraJvmArguments>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>hello.Application</mainClass>

                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>config</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- <tasks>
                                <copy todir="target/appassembler/data">
                                    <fileset dir="data"/>
                                </copy>
                            </tasks>-->
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: your base-package is correct? in haddop-context.xml take a look at this explanation about annotation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan

Comment: Yes..it is correct @ZaoTaoBao

Comment: what are jar files you have in buildpath? if you using maven post your pom.xml

Comment: pom.xml posted @Rembo

Comment: @Alina it will be great if you post details with the XML files. So, that will be easy to drill down towards error. And also post details if you have done any try and error. So, other people don't have to go through every iteration you already have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 'spring-boot-autoconfigure' missing, so I added following in dependencies in pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that your Spring Boot application doesn't load your hadoop-context.xml file. Try adding a @Configuration class that imports that file.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/hadoop-context.xml")
public class AppConfiguration {
}
```