# Apache Archiva 2.0 Jetty WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext

Tags: java, spring, jetty, embedded-jetty, archiva

I'm trying to stand up an instance of [Apache Archiva 2.0](http://archiva.apache.org/download.cgi).  I can successfully run the standalone on my box at home (Ubuntu 13) from the command line: archiva2.0/bin/archiva console... However, on my Redhat 6 box at work, Archiva fails to startup the Spring webapp context.  I only know the [very basics about Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456501/906048).  Below are the logs/files that I think are relevant.  If I am missing anything, let me know in a comment and I'll gladly update.

Archiva console output:

> 2014-02-28 06:18:09,935 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler [] - Shutting down ExecutorService 'springScheduler'
>   2014-02-28 06:18:09,935 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor [] - Shutting down ExecutorService
>   2014-02-28 06:18:09,935 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader [] - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'archivaUiServices': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationInterceptor#rest' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [1](http://archiva.apache.org/download.cgi); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationInterceptor#rest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.apache.archiva.redback.users.UserManager org.apache.archiva.redback.rest.services.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor.userManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userManager#archiva':                                          ....etc...

Tanuki Service Wrapper log:

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/28 06:18:02 | 2014-02-28 06:18:02.785:INFO:/:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/28 06:18:09 | 2014-02-28 06:18:09.944:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/devSpace/lib/apache-archiva-2.0.0/apps/archiva/},/devSpace/lib/apache-archiva-2.0.0/apps/archiva
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/28 06:18:09 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'archivaUiServices': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationInterceptor#rest' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [1](http://archiva.apache.org/download.cgi); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationInterceptor#rest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

archiva2.0/contexts/archiva.xml:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
   <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/apps/archiva</Set>
   <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
   <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

archiva2.0/apps/archiva/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
   default-lazy-init="true">
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.apache.archiva.web.api"/>
<util:properties id="archivaRuntimeProperties" location="classpath:application.properties" />
<bean id="jcr-repository" class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl" destroy-method="shutdown" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg ref="jcr-config"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jcr-config" class="org.apache.archiva.metadata.repository.jcr.ArchivaJcrRepositoryConfig" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg value="${appserver.base}/conf/repository.xml"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${appserver.base}/data/jcr"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Glad to finally have found the answer to this conundrum; the accepted answer is the solution! The errors didn't help at all. The problem appears to be triggered by some subtle variable in the OS or environment, but I couldn't find it. On two separate Debian 7.4 VM's (one local and one on our testing cluster) one Archiva 2.0.0 worked out of the box and the other gave above obscure error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue under some environments: [MRM-1807](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM-1807)

You can correct the issue by adding a correct file as `conf/archiva.xml` under the installation or base directory, for example: http://s.apache.org/default-archiva.xml

Comment: what makes the example correct?  I don't want to blow away my existing archiva.xml config if I can salvage some of it.