# Hibernate + Spring: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm currently setting up a project with Spring and Hibernate. After several other problems i got the next problem :P

Anyway. When call `entityManager.flush()` I get an exception: `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`.

I have annotated my class with `@Transactional`but it's still not working.

I read serval threads here where people had a similar problem, but the solution was always `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`. But I already have this configuration.

I am not sure what code or files I should provide you, so you can find the whole project here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Exc4dHICl-UDN3ZEJnbS1FZFk/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan) is post about config when `@Transactional` is not working - do you have tag `<context:component-scan>` in `appContext.xml` set? This both scans packages for beans to register and activates annotation. If you don't have a `<context:component-scan>` the `@Transactional` annotation will not wrapp the method in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution of this issue by implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and putting a self reference to the service call.

The issue arise because there is no transaction started in the calling method and since subsequent method calls are internal reference so no new transaction was created. So, I have to either make my calling method as transactional or create an internal reference and call the subsequent method through that reference.

You have to override the following method as

```
private MyService myService = myService;    
@Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
            myService = event.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyService.class);
        }
```

Then use `myService.myMethod()` instead of `myMethod()` where ever you want transaction to be active.