# When is @Autowired invoked for a bean?

Tags: java, spring

For a bean :

```
@Autowired
private MyBean myBean;
```

Is this bean autowired before :

```
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public String showView { 
  //myBean is null here
}
```

Reason I'm asking is that myBean is set to null. However for other beans which have

```
@RenderMapping("NORMAL")
public String renderNormal{ 
  //myBean is not null here
}
```

myBean seems to be autowired correctly.

Is `@RequestMapping("VIEW")` causing myBean to not be wired or is being invoked before Spring autowires myBean ? If so how I can I configure Spring to wire myBean before entering method showView ?

Update : I was missing `<context:annotation-config />` in Spring context file, this question provides some detail on its use : [Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan)

Comment: is your showView method in a class with annotation @Controller?

Comment: You need to show more Spring related code so we can figure out what's going on

Comment: You seem to be mixing concepts of Spring MVC and Spring beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alone `@RequestMapping` annotation doesn't make your class a Spring bean.

Usually, the `@RequestMapping` goes hand-by-hand with the `@Controller` annotation (which is extends the `@Component` annotation) so that it's considered as a Spring bean and (according to the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html)) to

> represent a component that receives HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse instances

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your showView Method is in a class annotated with annotation @Controller, you should have

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.path" />
```

where your.package.path is path in which you have your controller classes.

Also please see follwoing link for example:[Auto component scan example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/)