# Turn on Autowire in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I check my application without

```xml
<context:spring-configured/>
```

and the `@Autowire` working properly. I don't know how the container can auto inject without

```xml
<context:spring-configured/>
```

Here is my application-context.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-
    mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.somepackage" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
       <property name="converters">
           <set>
               <bean class="com.somepackage.converter.CategoryConverter"/>
           </set>
       </property>
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autowiring is working because of

`context:component-scan`

Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) javadoc

Answer (score 0):

You need to add context schema into your Configuration XML to use @Autowired annotation, like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

 <context:annotation-config/>
```

For more check the link below :

[3.11. Annotation-based configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)

Also, check the difference between [context:annotation-config vs context:component-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan) , You were getting @Autowiring because of the context:component-scan being used in your context schema.

Comment: my application can @Autowire the been without <context:annotation-config/> . I don't know why .

Comment: Since you have used <context:component-scan base-package="com.somepackage" />, so whichever comes into the package "com.somepackage" could be @Autowired that's why.