# Spring ApplicationContext closed before bean invoked

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

In my Spring app I noticed strange behavior of Spring (or Eclipse). It confused me. ApplicationContext surrounded with try/catch to be sure is closed after done in finally block. But in Eclipse console I saw that it closed before bean invoked.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            ApplicationContext context = null;
        try {
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "beans-annot.xml" });
            Launcher launcher = (Launcher) context.getBean("launcher");

                System.out.println(launcher);
                launcher.invokeBean();
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(context != null)
            ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).close();
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class Bean {
    public void invoke(){
        System.out.println("invoke bean");
    }
}
@Component
public class Launcher {

    @Autowired
    public Bean bean;

    //setter

    public void invokeBean(){
        bean.invoke();
    }
}
```

beans-annot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.ioc" />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

In Eclipse console output:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ IoC ---
окт 30, 2014 8:52:56 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6e4e4adb: startup date [Thu Oct 30 20:52:56 FET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
окт 30, 2014 8:52:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans-annot.xml]
my.ioc.Launcher@2b7f535d
окт 30, 2014 8:52:56 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6e4e4adb: startup date [Thu Oct 30 20:52:56 FET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
invoke bean
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see doClose method init before Bean, why? I think that it's Eclipse or maven plugin error... Project was build with exec-maven-plugin.

Comment: Could you post the `beans-annot.xml` file?

Comment: `System.out.println(launcher);` has been executed, that's why you can see `my.ioc.Launcher@2b7f535d`

Comment: But I don't know why `launcher.invokeBean();` does not show nothing in the Console

Comment: added beans-annot.xml

Comment: Is the invokeBean() method invoking it synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: Seems that just the output is being reordered. Are the log messages written to stdout or stderr?

Comment: @Henry bouth stdout and stderr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually working:

The line `System.out.println(launcher);` prints `my.ioc.Launcher@2b7f535d`

Just on

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans-annot.xml]
my.ioc.Launcher@2b7f535d <--------
окт 30, 2014 8:52:56 PM …..
```

The line `System.out.println("invoke bean");` prints `invoke bean` just how is expected.. where?

```
окт 30, 2014 8:52:56 PM ....ClassPathXmlApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support….root of context hierarchy
invoke bean <-------- 
[INFO] …
```

Your application is so short or fast in be executed, that when it is executed, you are seeing the information or output of your own application **together** with the Spring starting/closing information. So both are printed together, your app and spring (starting/closing) process, so in this case, therefore, the terminal/console is giving the impression you have described.

Try to enclose `System.out.println("invoke bean");` within a `Thread.sleep(5000)` to delay in some way your application.

About your XML application

1. For each .xsd remove the version, i.e.: spring-beans-3.0.xsd to spring-beans.xsd. It is a good practice **not** include the version
2. Remove `<context:annotation-config />` is not necessary because you already have `<context:component-scan base-package="my.ioc" />` declared, read the following: [`Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan/24083073#24083073) for more details.