# How to configure controller in spring without component scanning in xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, component-scan

I have to design a very large scale project for a bank using spring mvc. I already choose to go with the XML configuration. My concern is to limit the start up time of the server. There will be approximately 2000 controllers.

I already use component scan for scanning the `@Controller`. It worked fine. But, the problem is when I remove the component scan from XML and add the controller bean using bean configuration manually in XML, it didn't create the instance of controller in IOC container. And gives me the 404 not found error. So how can I configure the controller without component scanning in XML.

Followings are my code samples. Any help?

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="" />-->
</beans>
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="dataContext/data-context.xml" />

    <bean id="contactSetupController" class="com.stl.afs.ci.cca.controller.ContactSetupController">
        <property name="contactSetupDao" ref="contactSetupDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contactSetupDao" class="com.stl.afs.ci.cca.controller.ContactSetupDao" scope="prototype">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**ContactSetupController.java**

```
package com.stl.afs.ci.cca.controller;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contactsetup")
public class ContactSetupController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactSetupController.class);


    private ContactSetupDao contactSetupDao;

    public void setContactSetupDao(ContactSetupDao contactSetupDao) {
        this.contactSetupDao = contactSetupDao;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap model) {
        contactSetupDao.showDepedency();

        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world! Nice to see you in the planet");
        return "ci/contactsetup/index";
    }
}
```

**ContactSetupDao.java**

```
package com.stl.afs.ci.cca.controller;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ARNAB on 1/8/2015.
 */
public class ContactSetupDao {
    public ContactSetupDao() {
        System.out.println("------DAO------");
    }

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + sessionFactory);
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void showDepedency(){
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM customers");
        int i = 0;
        for (Object o : query.list()) {
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your controllers should be in the `servlet-context.xml` not the `root-context.xml`. Your dao should also be a singleton not prototype (there is no state so it makes no sense to make it prototype scoped). Also when using component scanning (which I really suggest you do) you shouldn't use `""` for scanning as that scans everything, you should limit it to your own package(s) and for the `servlet-context` to scan only for controllers. This will reduce the amount of classes to scan and speedup your startup time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem why you get `404 - Not Found` is use of tag `<context:annotation-config/>` *only*.

`<context:annotation-config/>` only activates the annotation on the beans which are already registered with your application context and does basic *autowiring* for you. It does not auto-detect and register beans.

So there are no as such no `Controllers` available for you to handle request.

In order to configure controllers you **either** switch back to `context:component-scan` which anyways is working for you (*do consider taking M. Deinum suggestion while reverting*) **or** manually configure the controllers to respective URL's via `HandlerMappings` such as [SimpleUrlHanslerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html) (*not recommended due to verbosity involved*)

**P.S.:** Do read [this fabulous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan) discussing the differences between `<context:annotation-config>` and `<context:component-scan>`

Answer (score 1):

`How can I configure the controller without component scanning in XML?`. you can use annotation based configuration to avoid XML.

check this [EnableWebMvc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) configuration. I configured a spring3.2 project without xml configuration. it was totally annotation based.

overwrite startup of web application **[`Initializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)** :

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException 
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));        
    }
}
```

Configuration file for application context

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.paul.nkp")     // set your root package, it will scan all sub-package
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:com/paul/nkp/application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * configured for read property values using @Value attibutes
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public static MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws PropertyVetoException, IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        ......
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        System.out.println("Session Factory Init");

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

Now everything in code, no xml manipulation. There is a [`ComponentScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation in configuration file, which scan all spring annotation from you base package.

Comment: But i don,t want to use component scan. Because it increases server start up time. There will be approximately 2000 controllers, services and daos. However, i already configured it with xml and lazy loading of beans so that when server starts up it takes minimum time.

Comment: then you have to `manually configure the controllers to respective URL's` as said @Bond