# Unable to autowire attributes in package

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

For some reason, in my config package, I can not autowire fields while in my controller package, there does not seem to be any problem.

For instance:

servlet-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="service, controller, config" />
```

root-context.xml (tried adding service here as well)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="security" />
```

This does not work: Setup class inside the config package. I receive a null pointer error.

```
@Component
public class Setup { //inside the config package
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; //null pointer error
    /*..other stuff */
}
```

This does work: A controller inside the controller package:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/contact")
public class ContactController { //inside the controller package
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; //this works
    /*..other stuff..*/
}
```

Why does it work for the controller package but not config package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because probably the **@Service** class **UserService** is not visible in any of the two packages "**config**" or "**controller**" I assume you would also need a component scan for the packages containing the services:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="service" />
```

**Edit:**

Usually you should remember that if a **Bean**/**Component** is not within the scanned context it will always be **null** on injection (autowiring).

**EDIT 2:**

So as you've probably seen Spring has two type of contexts, the **ApplicationContext** and the **ServletContext**. If you scan a bean in the **ServletContext** it will be accessible only from **Controllers** (or as the name states from the servlets), but beans scanned by the **ApplicationContext** are also accessible from **Services** or other **Components** and any servlet can access beans scanned here without having to scan them in the servlet context.

In your case you should have the following setup:

In **servlet-context.xml**:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
```

In **applicationContext.xml** or **root-context.xml** (I assume you've referenced it as so in the web.xml)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="config, security, services" />
```

The image bellow illustrates the context hierarchy from Spring:

[image]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this still does not work. 
I have a feeling this may be caused because I have 2 xml's: root-context.xml and servlet-context.xml. I updated my post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bogdan. Unfortunately this does not work as well. The userService is still null inside the config.Setup class.
If there is anything I can provide for more clarity please let me know.

Comment: @Moody write me a private message on linkedin or my blog and I'll help you fix it and then we will post the proper solution here

Answer (score 1):

Try using this configuration instead:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="config,controller" />
```

Comment: you can find more details on annotation based bean configuration here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately it does not work. I have also tried to follow the post you gave me (although they used seperate setter methods and put the autowired above them), it still did not work.