# Java Spring Test Autowired Controller is null error

Tags: java, spring

I would like to test a Java Web Controller using Spring (Not Spring Boot).

My Controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderHdrController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getOrderList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getOrderTables(OrderSearchDto orderSearchDto) { ... }
}
```

And my test class is:

```
public class FilterActivityTest2 {

    @Autowired
    private OrderHdrController orderHdrController;

    @Test
    public void testActivity() {
        OrderSearchDto orderSearchDto = new OrderSearchDto();
        OrderSearchPanelDto orderSearchPanelDto = new OrderSearchPanelDto();
        orderSearchPanelDto.setActivityTypes(Arrays.asList("TAKEOVER","DELIVERY"));
        orderSearchDto.setOrderSearchPanelDto(orderSearchPanelDto);
        Map<String, Object>  result =  orderHdrController.getOrderTables(orderSearchDto);
        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

I do not want to mock any objects. I just want to run the test on the controller all the way to the db. But when I debug into the test, the orderHdrController is null in testActivity method.

What have I done wrong? Please help or ask me for more information. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring unit test objects autowired with null fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046360/spring-unit-test-objects-autowired-with-null-fields)

Comment: Try SpringRunner with `@RunWith`

Comment: I think you're missing `@RunWith` and use `@InjectMock` instead of `@Autorwired`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am using Spring, not Spring Boot. What @RunWith do I use?

Comment: try this at top of FilterActivityTest2 class  @SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootDemoApplication.class, 
            webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

Comment: Add @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class) to your class

Answer (score 2):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(OrderHdrController.class)
public class FilterActivityTest2 {

    @Autowired
    private OrderHdrController orderHdrController;

    @Test
    public void testActivity() {
        OrderSearchDto orderSearchDto = new OrderSearchDto();
        OrderSearchPanelDto orderSearchPanelDto = new OrderSearchPanelDto();
        orderSearchPanelDto.setActivityTypes(Arrays.asList("TAKEOVER","DELIVERY"));
        orderSearchDto.setOrderSearchPanelDto(orderSearchPanelDto);
        Map<String, Object>  result =  orderHdrController.getOrderTables(orderSearchDto);
        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

> or If dont using any spring or junit  then why using @test

**simply make a main class**

```
public class FilterActivityTest2{

    public static void main(String args[]){

 ....... put your tast case code here 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `FilterActivityTest2` needs to be managed by the Spring context, to be able to autowire dependencies.

To do that, either annotate your test class with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

Or extend the main test class that already has these annotations. If you created your project using spring initializer, you'll find that class in the tests created for you.

```
public class FilterActivityTest2 extends MyApplicationTests {
```

**EDIT**

For Spring, you can use [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-contextconfiguration). [Here](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/contextconfiguration-example-spring-test) is a good tutorial.
Also see the official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing).

Comment: I'm using Spring, not Spring Boot. How can I change it to Spring?

Comment: @AlanTT Similar stuff, you can use [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-contextconfiguration).

Comment: @AlanTT I added a link to an example in my answer.

Comment: He is asking for away to have a spring test that is not spring boot. The other answer is correct.

Comment: @Kartik Thanks for your answer. I followed your recommendation to create a java configuration. But in my orderHdrController, I have OrderHdrRepository which is an Interface. How can I inject an OrderHdrRepository Bean in the Config java file? I cannot instantiate **new OrderHdrRepository()**

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov yep, OP edited the question after I had posted the answer. So I added my edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use spring boot then you can create the application context manually

```java
    @Before
    public void init() {
        ApplicationContext context = desired implementation;
        controller = context.getBean("bean name");
    }
```

But better do this

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FilterActivityTest2 {

    private OrderHdrController orderHdrController;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;
    @MockBean
    private  Dao dao;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        orderHdrController = new OrderHdrController(service, dao ....);
    }

    @Test
    ....
}
```