# Can't configure Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have big problem with configuring Spring MVC application. No matter what I write in configuration xmls I get 404 while reaching localhost/appname/ or localhost/appname/register . Why that happens? Read tutorials for MVC in Maven and it looks like I'm doing everything as they says.

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Wymysl to!</display-name>




    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="wymysl.Controllers" /> 
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

     <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>



</beans>
```

RegisterController.java

```
package wymysl.Controllers;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import wymysl.database.Person;
import wymysl.database.PersonsRepository;


@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    PersonsRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register() {


        return "register";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("Person") Person person) {

        System.out.println(""+person.getName());

        return "index";

    }



}
```

[image: ProjectTree]

Comment: Actually, you don't map "/". Try to call `localhost/appname/register`

Comment: Tried this also but without effect

Comment: @Mike Raphael is right you don't have a "/" mapping in your controller like this,  @RequestMapping("/")
 public String showIndexPage() {

  return "index";
 }

Comment: @Mike one more thing, when I run my web-app locally (via Tomcat 7) my URL also includes the port number I am using with Tomcat, i.e. like this: localhost:8080/appname/register. not sure if this is absolutely necessary but that is how I locate my jsps locally may be worth a try

Comment: @smoggers Good point.

Comment: In your server logs showing as org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound?

Answer (score 1):

Things you can change to make it more basic:-

1. Remove

   contextConfigLocation
               /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml

   ```
       <listener>
           <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
       </listener>
   ```

put your web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml at same path.

2. No need of 
   `<context:annotation-config />` as it is already taken care by component-scan. See here:- [Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan)   and `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>`
3. Make sure register.jsp is present in /WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp.

If issue still does not get solved you need to share your server logs.

Comment: I made changes you suggested and now my app at least starts on localhost/appname/ url but every other url than /index.jsp is giving 404. Also, index.jsp is loaded as raw html without imported css files. Before writing web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml when I could open these files by direct path in tomcat everything was okay.