# why @autowired is not working when I access a bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired

When I access a bean from spring bean configuration file using BeanFactory like this:

```
public class Person {
    private String id,address;
    @Autowired
    private Customer customer;
     //setters & getters
    }
```

and bean configuration file

```
<bean name="person" class="com.ram.spring.model.Person"></bean>
<bean class="com.ram.spring.model.Customer">
    <property name="email" value="ram@adp.com"></property>
    <property name="name" value="Ram"></property>
</bean>
```

here is the executor class

```
public class PersonExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BeanFactory context = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("Spring.xml"));
        Person person = (Person)context.getBean("person");
        System.out.println(person.getCustomer());
    }

}
```

when I execute this, I got `null`.is BeanFactory not supported for annotations?? any ideas??

Comment: Have you configured annotation support in your dispatcher-servlet.xml file??

Comment: I don't understand why so many same answer? while @jens has already answered same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jens suggested

you should active `annotation scan`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package_path">
</context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config />
```

hope that helped

Comment: Once again, I insist: there are no `@Component`, so `<context:component-scan />` is overkill.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1:** Include below code in your xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Remaining bean declaration -->
</beans>
```

---

**Approach 2:** Remove `@Autowired` and inject customer in your xml file only.

```
<bean name="person" class="com.ram.spring.model.Person">
    <property name="customer" ref="customer"></property>
</bean>
<bean name="customer" class="com.ram.spring.model.Customer">
    <property name="email" value="ram@adp.com"></property>
    <property name="name" value="Ram"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: `component-scan` is not required here (there is no `@Component` annotation). `annotation-config` would suffice (see [this (very detailed) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456501/1734119) for the difference between the two).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` or 
you have to add  to yor Spring.xml to activate the annotation scan.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why doesn't it work?

When using Spring with an XML context, using annotations is not activated by default. This means `@Autowired`, `@Transactional`, `@PostConstruct` and any other annotation you will use will simply not be exploited.

#### How do I fix it?

To make Spring aware of annotations, you need to add the following line:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Thus, Spring will search for annotations in the beans it creates and process them accordingly.

This requires activating the `context` namespace. At the top of your context, make sure you have all `context` related links and arguments<sup>1</sup>:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Your context -->
</beans>
```

You do *not* need `<context:component-scan />` in your case. This would be useful if you used full-annotation context (e.g. classes annotated with `@Component`). See the difference between `<context:annotation-config />` and `<context:component-scan />` [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456501/1734119).

#### Alternate solution

As [Naman Gala suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219658/1734119), you could also drop `@Autowired` completely and inject all dependencies in XML. See [the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219658/1734119) for more details.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This includes the `xmlns:context` attribute (xmlns = XML NameSpace) and two URLs in `xsi:schemaLocation`.</sub>