# No bean named is defined Exception

Tags: java, spring

package com.mkyong.output;
IOutputGenerator.java

```
public interface IOutputGenerator
{
    public void generateOutput();
}
```

package com.mkyong.output;
OutputHelper.java

```
@Component
public class OutputHelper {

    @Autowired
    IOutputGenerator outputGenerator;

    public void generateOutput() {
        outputGenerator.generateOutput();
    }

    /*//DI via setter method
    public void setOutputGenerator(IOutputGenerator outputGenerator) {
        this.outputGenerator = outputGenerator;
    }*/
}
```

package com.mkyong.output.impl;

CsvOutputGenerator.java

```
@Component
public class CsvOutputGenerator implements IOutputGenerator {
    public void generateOutput() {
        System.out.println("This is Csv Output Generator");
    }
}
```

SpringBeans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong" />

</beans>
```

i am getting this exception Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'OutputHelper' is defined

even though i have marked OutputHelper as component.

Comment: what is the package definition of `OutputHelper`?

Comment: Please make sure that your class in the package "com.mkyong"

Comment: @sidgate package updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed

```
OutputHelper output = (OutputHelper) context.getBean("OutputHelper");
```

to

```
OutputHelper output = (OutputHelper) context.getBean("outputHelper");
```

and it worked.

Comment: thats because by default, Spring will lower case the first character of  components, so Outputhelper becomes outputHelper

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you haven't added following in your Spring XML configuration

```
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: this is not a mvc application

Answer (score 0):

you need to see top exception and read the whole line.
i guess there have a exception is nested exception just like @Autowired xxxxxx,meas autowired fail.
i have notice this:

```
@Autowired
IOutputGenerator outputGenerator;
```

and

```
@Component
public class CsvOutputGenerator implements IOutputGenerator
```

so, in the default, class name is used to @Autowired，you can rewrite to

```
@Autowired
IOutputGenerator csvOutputGenerator;
```

notice:
"csvOutputGenerator" first letter is lowercase

Comment: Did you try this change?
@Autowired
IOutputGenerator csvOutputGenerator;

Comment: i changed OutputHelper output = (OutputHelper)context.getBean("OutputHelper"); to OutputHelper output = (OutputHelper)context.getBean("outputHelper"); and it worked

Answer (score 0):

the easier option would be to enable annotations in beans already registered in the application context, means that you can just use `@Autowired` instead of getting manually all beans with `context.getBean()`

just add this line to your SpringBeans.xml
`<context:annotation-config>`

if you really want to understand what you are doing reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456501/2894562) could help.