# I can't autowire repository in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to autowire repository in controller using spring annotation. I am getting error `org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor class not found` for which I couldn't find a solution.

Error that I am getting:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.payforeign.article.ArticleRepository com.payforeign.article.ArticleController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor
```

**Controller**

```java
package com.payforeign.article;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class ArticleController {

   @Autowired
   private ArticleRepository repository;

   //controller methods
}
```

**Repository**

I have annotated repository with `@Repository`. According to spring documentation I am having only repository interface. Is it correct?

```java
package com.payforeign.article;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends CrudRepository<Article, Long> {}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

I have included `jpa:repositories` with correct `base-package` and `component-scan`. I have specified that it is annotation driven (`<mvc:annotation-driven /> <tx:annotation-driven />`) and added JDBC and JPA settings. My applicationContext.xml is correctly loaded from web.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans ...>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.payforeign,com.payforeign.article" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.payforeign.article" />

    <!-- Data Source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/payforeign" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.payforeign.article" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: The stack trace is clear: You're missing the Spring Data JARs from your CLASSPATH.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` nearly always means a version mismatch. In this case, I believe you need the RC versions (or at least the very latest release versions) to get query-by-example.

Comment: I have upgraded `spring-data-commons` from version 1.11.4 to 1.12.1 and it fixed the issue. Thanks @chrylis

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue is about dependencies.

The class, you are looking for is here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.java

As you can see, the latest version of spring-data-jpa has it, therefore you should either upgrade your failing delendency to the latest version or downdrade spring-data-jpa version a little bit (not recommended).

I had similar problem in my application with spring boot and mongoDB jpa repositories.

As example, I have spring-data-jpa and spring-data-mongodb dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But spring boot spring-boot-starter-data-jpa implicitly uses an older version of spring-data-mongodb than 1.9.2.RELEASE.
The easiest way to fix was to downgrade  spring-data-mongodb to 1.8.4.RELEASE version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this config in your applicationContext.xml

```xml
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: According to answer on [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456501/1997088](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456501/1997088) `<context:component-scan>` can do job of `<context:annotation-config/>` and annotation-config is then not required

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter `NoClassDefFoundError`  if the version of `spring-data-commons` is older then required by `spring-data-jpa`. This exception nearly always means a version mismatch (*dependency hell*). Here's an example of such a bad dependency combination:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The solution is as simple as removing `spring-data-commons` from your project dependencies (anyway you don't need to explicitly specify this library cause it's a transitive dependency of `spring-data-jpa`).

Comment: I was referring multiple spring-data dependencies namely spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-data-rest, from my pom, which caused the trouble. Removal of the unwanted solved the issue in my case. This answer helped me getting this idea.

Answer (score -3):

Please change the

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.payforeign,com.payforeign.article" />
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.payforeign" />
```

It is define the base package using this you **com.payforeign.article** will automatically scan.