# Exception when i use bean post processor

Tags: java, spring

When i use this :

```
<bean id="circle" class="com.sameer.Learning.Circle" />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>
```

in my spring.xml i am getting runtime exceptions :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
```

The bean doesnt get created. But when i used :

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

The bean was created and i did not get any exception. 
Can anybody please tell me why ?

Spring - 4.3.7 
JDK - 1.8

Edited - Added spring.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- <bean id="triangle" class="com.sameer.Learning.Triangle">
    <property name="pointA" ref="pointA" />
    <property name="pointB" ref="pointB" />
    <property name="pointC" ref="pointC" />


</bean> -->
<bean id="pointA" class="com.sameer.Learning.Point">
    <qualifier value="circleRelated"></qualifier>
    <property name="x" value="0"></property>
    <property name="y" value="0"></property>

</bean>

<bean id="pointB" class="com.sameer.Learning.Point">
    <property name="x" value="-20"></property>
    <property name="y" value="0"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="pointC" class="com.sameer.Learning.Point">
    <property name="x" value="20"></property>
    <property name="y" value="0"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="circle" class="com.sameer.Learning.Circle" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>
```

'

The above is the spring .xml file i used to inject dependency
The below is the code where i want to inject the object 
Code -

```
  package com.sameer.Learning;



    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
      import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;
      import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
      import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
       public class Circle implements Shape {


    private Point center;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;


    public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
        return messageSource;
    }


    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("circleRelated")
    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

    public void draw() {

        System.out.println("Point is " + center.getX() + "," +center.getY());
        //System.out.println(this.messageSource.getMessage("greeting",null,"Default",null));
}
}
```

Comment: please, show code of your beans and xml file

Comment: Have you tried to define the circle bean after the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor ?

Comment: @Nikolay i have added the code and spring.xml

Comment: @sharon182 Yes i tried

Comment: where is your declaration of bean MessageSource  ?

Comment: @sharon182 pls ignore that. am looking to set the value of center

Comment: Post the complete exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bean `Circle` has autowired dependencies `MessageSource` and `Point`. So, you should pass it into xml-file manually:

```
<bean id="circle" class="com.sameer.Learning.Circle" >
    <property name="messageSource" ref="..." />
    <property name="center" ref="..." />
</bean>
```

or add `<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>`.

> **context:annotation-config**  is used to activate applied annotations in already registered beans in application context.

After adding this annotation Spring "see" your annotations `@Autowired` and can automatically inject needed dependencies from application context.

Look a similar question - [Difference between context:annotation-config vs context:component-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan)