# Spring Filter components in auto scanning

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control, component-scan

I have a Spring MVC app. ( an application framework and inversion of control container for the Java platform. The framework's core features can be used by any Java application, but there are extensions for building web applications on top of the Java EE (Enterprise Edition) platform) using this Spring filtering, Now using spring filter

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis"  >
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController"/>
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.pq.workflow.web.controller.WorkflowController"/>
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex"      expression="com.pastis.pq.workflow.web.*" />
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex"      expression="com.pastis.security.*" />
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex"      expression="com\.pastis\.security\..*" />
</context:component-scan>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.pastis.repositories"/>
```

also tried:

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis.security">
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package=" com.pastis.pq">
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.pq.workflow.web.controller.WorkflowController"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.pq.workflow.web.controller.WorkflowAdminController"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

but I have a problem with the `WorkflowController`

and this controller:

```
com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController
```

nevertheless when I start the app. I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManagerController':
```

the servlet-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Use annotations to inject stuff -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis.pq" use-default-filters="false" >
        <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.pastis.pq.web.endpoint.*" />
        <!--context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.pastis.pq.web."-/-->
    </context:component-scan>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.pastis.pq.repositories"/>

    <!-- main datasource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- spring data repositories -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.pastis.pq.repositories"/>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">

        <property name="database" value="H2" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pastis-entities" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
              <value>com.pastis.pq.model</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="eclipselink.target-database">org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.target-server">WebLogic</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- customizable database configuration -->
    <bean id="dataConfig" class="com.pastis.commons.services.SystemConfig">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="test-config.properties"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

 
       
</beans>
```

the console when I run the tests:

```
2020-10-08 10:46:57,315 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'securityManagerController'
2020-10-08 10:46:57,315 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'securityManagerController'
2020-10-08 10:46:57,315 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'securityManagerController'
2020-10-08 10:46:57,315 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'securityManagerController'
2020-10-08 10:46:57,317 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Registered injected element on class [com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController]:
```

Comment: First of all, your exclude filter is obsolete, see the package paths. Second, you need to provide more information. Full stacktrace or at least the whole error message. It probably tells you which dependency is missing. You also have to show your WebApplicationContext config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial code snippet is right, but you are not defining the right package for component scanning.

If the class you want to exclude is this:

```java
com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController
```

Instead of this XML fragment:

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis.pq"  >
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController"/>
</context:component-scan>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.pastis.pq.repositories"/>
```

You need something like:

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis">
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController"/>
</context:component-scan>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.pastis.pq.repositories"/>
```

Please, notice the change in the package name from `com.pastis.pq` to `com.pastis`.

Or better, define another `component-scan` element for that purpose:

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis.pq" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis.security">
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController"/>
</context:component-scan>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.pastis.pq.repositories"/>
```

Please, do not forget to remove the attribute `use-default-filters="false"`from the `<context:component-scan>`element. As indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.27.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-filters):

> You can also disable the default filters by setting `useDefaultFilters=false` on the annotation or providing `use-default-filters="false"` as an attribute of the `<component-scan/>` element. This will in effect disable automatic detection of classes annotated with `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Controller`, or `@Configuration`.

This is very likely the reason why in one of the approaches you tried Spring was unable to identify the beans in your `com.pastis.pq.web.endpoint.*` package.

As long as you are using `<context:component-scan>`, probably you can get rid of the `<context:annotation-config>` element. Please, see [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-and-contextcomponent-scan) here in stackoverflow.

**UPDATE**

After the different changes in the question, I think that this XML configuration should work properly:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis.pq">
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.pq.workflow.web.controller.WorkflowController"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.pq.workflow.web.controller.WorkflowAdminController"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pastis.security">
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.pastis.security.controller.SecurityManagerController"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.pastis.pq.repositories"/>

    <!-- main datasource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- spring data repositories -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.pastis.pq.repositories"/>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">

        <property name="database" value="H2" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pastis-entities" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
              <value>com.pastis.pq.model</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="eclipselink.target-database">org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.target-server">WebLogic</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- customizable database configuration -->
    <bean id="dataConfig" class="com.pastis.commons.services.SystemConfig">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="test-config.properties"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I updated the question, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Plase, can you update also your ```servlet-xml``` configuration? If your first snippet is the right one, you need to modify your exclusion filters based on regex with something like ```<context:exclude-filter type="regex"      expression="com\.pastis\.security\..*" />```. You need to properly escape the regex special characters. Please, can you try?

Comment: I've tried also this... I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I am sorry to hear it. I updated my answer again. Please, can you try this exact XML configuration and see if it works? Are you using any kind of additional configuration?