# How to configure <context:component-scan /> in Spring dispatch servlet?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0

I want to call a controller method in `oauth2` class
`org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/authorize", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void approveOrDeny(@RequestParam("user_oauth_approval")
                          boolean approved,
                          HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
                                                               ServletException {
....
}
```

from my application. To call the above class I tried using this. The result was "unable to access".

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.stjude.ri.bwfp">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="org.springframework.security.oauth2.*"/>
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
        type="regex" />
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
```

How can I call the controller class methods in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.*`?

Comment: The following answer also can be helpful: [@Service are constructed twice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4335438/814702)

Answer (score 3):

Since dispatcher-servlet beans should normally be `@Controller`s only, you should not exclude them. We are using this one in our `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, with OAuth, and it works fine:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.controllers" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```