# Spring can't inject property value using Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and i can't inject property value using `@Value` annotation in my controller class. Here is my controller:

```
 @Controller
    public class MailController {
        @Value("${mail.server.username}")
        private String destinationEmail;
        ...
        }
```

And here is my application context xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.content.stream">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <!--<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:content-stream.properties" />-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="classpath:content-stream.properties" name="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

    <import resource="security.xml" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>mymessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.content.stream.entities"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${mail.server.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${mail.server.port}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mail.server.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mail.server.password}" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <util:properties location="classpath:javamail.properties" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="destinationEmail" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="${mail.server.username}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateMailMessage"
          class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
        <property name="text">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[
            Уважаемый, %s!
            Содержымое : %s
            С уважением %s !
            ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I read many answers on stack but in my case nothing to work. Content of my propery file:

```
...
#Mail properties
mail.server.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.server.port=587
mail.server.username=myemail@gmail.com
mail.server.password=password
```

Comment: share contents in `content-stream.properties` file.

Comment: @DilipKumar i shared

Comment: Your commented line `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:content-stream.properties" />` should work? what exception your getting when using this line?

Comment: @DilipKumar I haven't gotten exceptions, just my destinationEmail field value is `${mail.server.username}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your commented line `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:content-stream.properties" />` not working, then you can get work in other way.

load property file using

`<util:properties id="contentProps" location="content-stream.properties" />`

Make sure you have the following at the top of your file to include the "util" namespace:

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xsi:schemaLocation= "... http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
```

Next, you can access properties in controller like

```
@Value("#{contentProps['mail.server.username']}")
private String destinationEmail;
```

This will help you to organize multiple properties in different files.

**UPDATE:**

As far i know, we can't directly inject properties in spring controller.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102216/why-is-spring-value-incompatible-with-controller) for why you can't use Value with Controller.

But you can achieve this by two ways:

1. Above approach, using util properties.
2. Using one dedicated config class to serve properties to controller. 
   like as below

   ```
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:content-stream.properties")
   public class AppConfig {
       @Value("${mail.server.username}")
       private String destinationEmail;

       // getters
   }
   ```

Autowire `AppConfig` in your controller, access value using getter.

> In Second option you don't need any xml configuration.

Comment: thanks a lot it's working but, maybe, you will explain why `${mail.server.username}` not working

Comment: Still helpful and relevant today. The config class was the most important part. You can access the config class using @Autowired