# Pointcut to Spring @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, mapping, aop, pointcut

I'm just now trying to enable AOP on my Spring project. I want to execute code (a session cleaning) AFTER the @RequestMapping has completed. Here is my **applicationContext.xml** (simply load referenced resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- Include context files from different layers -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <import resource="classpath:appname-security-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:appname-service-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:appname-dao-context.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**the security context:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
<intercept-url pattern='/pages/login.jsp' />
<intercept-url pattern="/secure/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<form-login login-page="/pages/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.jsp?login_error=true"  /> 
        <logout logout-success-url="/pages/logout-redirect.jsp" invalidate-session="true" />
        <remember-me key="appnameRMKey" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService' >
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="springSecurityDataSource" />
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT username,password,enabled FROM Users WHERE username = ?" />
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT u.username, a.authorityname FROM Users u JOIN Users_Authorities ua on u.id = ua.user_id JOIN Authorities a on ua.authorities_id = a.id WHERE u.username = ?" />
    </beans:bean>   

    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- Apply security for all beans where security was set -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->

    <global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class = "true" secured-annotations="enabled">
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* appname.UsersDAO.*(..))" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* appname.AuthoritiesDAO.*(..))" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
    </global-method-security>
</beans:beans>
```

**my service context:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- Scan for service layer annotated beans -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<context:component-scan base-package="appname" scoped-proxy="interfaces" />
<aop:config  proxy-target-class="true">
    </aop:config>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- Mark bean transactions as annotation driven -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

**my web context:**(BEAN DEFINITION OMITTED FOR SHORTNESS!!)

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>    
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.skyway.spring.util.web.binary.ModelBindingMultipartResolver" />
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
    <bean id="streamedBinaryContentView" class="org.skyway.spring.util.web.binary.ModelAttributeStreamer" />
    <bean id="beanNameViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="iPhoneUserAgentViewResolver" class="org.skyway.spring.util.viewresolution.UserAgentViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="agentSubstring" value="iPhone" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/iphone/" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean><bean id="webInfViewResolver" class="org.skyway.spring.util.viewresolution.AbsolutePathViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="order" value="-1" />
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="appname" scoped-proxy="interfaces" />
    <aop:config  proxy-target-class="true">
    </aop:config>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    </beans>
```

this is **the interface of aspect** class

```
package appname;
import it.pstmarche.model.HibernateSessionFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@Aspect
public interface SessionInterceptor {

@Pointcut("execution(public * appname.ImplantManager+.*(..))")
public void pc() ;

@Before("pc()")
public void print();
}
```

the implementation is trivial
    *@Before("pc()")
    public void print(){
    System.out.println("About to make call to print Hello World"
    }*

I also tried some other expressions like:

- @Pointcut("execution(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping public * appname.*(..))")
- and many others

with no luck. I start thinking the problem is not the expression (i already tried about 10-15 types...) but the class not being considered in the context.

For answer, take in consideration:

- the name appname is intended for example, obviusly
- inserting the aop:config and aop:aspectj-autoproxy are only a try because i also readed in other threads that the config must be enabled in every file that is loaded by applicationContext. I also tried inserting only in one but no result
- the controller has the annotated interface + annotated implementation. i also tried without annotating the interface or removing completely with no result

any help? :)

EDIT: in response to axtavt .. sorry i forgot to add my web.xml, here is a piece of it

```
<servlet>
<description>context-servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>appname Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:appname-web-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

i correctly load the contextConfigLocation via web-context.xml file. Sorry i forgot it :-(

EDIT2: I got the answer following my mistake by the suggestion of axtavt! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AOP is configured at per-context basis.

You have two contexts - root web application context (`applicationContext.xml`, which includes config files imported into it), and application context of `DispatcherServlet`, where controllers beans are declared.

So, in order to apply aspects to controllers you need to add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>` to servlet-specific context.

Also note that you shouldn't use `<context:component-scan>` over the same base package in different contexts, see [@Service are constructed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333390/service-are-constructed-twice).

Comment: updated question. 

so i define dispatcher context well, but the problem is related to multiple context:component-scan maybe?

Comment: Update: THANKS. i figured out what i missed: to scan the correct package under the DispatcherServlet context! I scanned correctly under all the other file of the application context, but not on this (that is only the requested..and i missed it!) Thank you again!