# "No Session found for current thread" when adding @Autowire

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've seen several similar questions, but none of the suggested solutions helped me.

Summary: when I create and inject the beans on the .xml, it works; but when I use @Autowire or @Resource, it doesn't.

Environment: Spring3, Hibernate4, Tomcat7.

Details: the following setup DOES work:

`web.xml`:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
      /WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml
      /WEB-INF/spring/users-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

`root-context.xml`:

```
  <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/venus" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.airbus.genesis.marte.dal" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
  <bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>
```

`users-context.xml`:

```
  <bean id="usersDAO" class="com.airbus.genesis.marte.dal.users.UsersDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>
```

BL object:

```
@Service("usersManager")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UsersManager implements IUsersManager {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("usersDAO")
  private IUsersDAO usersDAO;

  @Override
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return usersDAO.getUsers();
  }

}
```

DAO object (notice that @Repository and @Resource are commented):

```
//@Repository("usersDAO")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UsersDAO implements IUsersDAO {

  // @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> res = (List<User>) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from User").list();
    return res;
  }

  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

But the following one DOES NOT work:

`users-context.xml`:

```
<!-- 
  <bean id="usersDAO" class="com.airbus.genesis.marte.dal.users.UsersDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>
-->
```

DAO object (notice that @Repository and @Resource are uncommented now):

```
@Repository("usersDAO")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UsersDAO implements IUsersDAO {

  @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> res = (List<User>) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from User").list();
    return res;
  }

  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread` is raised:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:941)
    com.airbus.genesis.marte.dal.users.UsersDAO.getUsers(UsersDAO.java:23)
    com.airbus.genesis.marte.bl.users.UsersManager.getUsers(UsersManager.java:22)
[...]
```

The same happens if I use @Autowire instead of @Resource.

I guess it is some kind of misunderstanding on my side, but cannot find where. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that `@Repository` and `@Service` annotations are being picked up in the dispatcher-servlet.xml configuration (do you use `context:component-scan`?), so these beans are created in the dispatcher servlet context instead of the root web app context.

A good practice is to put your service layer objects to the dedicated packages and use the specific package name as `<context:component-scan`/> `base-package` qualifier (like 'com.myproject.services'). You can also use filter expressions to include and exclude elements see examples here : [@Service are constructed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333390/service-are-constructed-twice)
and 4.10.3 section of the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters)

See also [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)

Comment: This is the solution. CopyPasteException on my side.