# Spring 3 Application Context loading

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I am a bit familiar with Spring framework but am still having lots of question concerning use of spring from project architectural view point. Now I am setting up Spring 3 and a Maven web application and am willing to try out all the the fancy component-scan's and autowiring features however this is where I get confused.

I am trying to break the project into sub-modules. And at some point these sub-modules may include `something-context.xml` in `classpath*:resource/META-INF`, like for instance when I will want to define a datSource related stuff in a separate module. So that's fine spring let's you load context files from within class-paths of all of the jars.

But here is where it gets vague - say I am using component scan. I am obviously using spring `DispatcherServlet` and it needs a servlet context to be loaded, and then there is a global application context parameter specified in web.xml `contextConfigLocation`.

So now servlet context config has a component-scan feature enabled for `com.mycom.project.controllers` and context loaded in the global `contextConfigLocation` has a context loaded with component scan feature for package `com.mycom.project` also searches for `classpath*:META-INF/spring/*-context.xml`.

So my question is - does this load controller's twice given that component scan is used for a for `com.mycom.project.controllers` and `com.mycom.project`? Or is it all loaded into one huge container and the `contextConfigLocation` parameter for either `DispatcherServlet` or global declaration is sort of access issue ? As in `DispatcherServlet` will reach only what's defined in `servlet-context.xml` but won't be able to use anything else?

And if my assumption is wrong, could I have a suggestion on how to manage multi-module project issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you might run into trouble. See this link for how to solve your problem.

[@Service are constructed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333390/service-are-constructed-twice)

The way you proceed when creating modules seems valid to me. You have a context.xml file for each module and all will get loaded once you load the application. Your modules are self-contained and can also be used in different environments. That's pretty much the way I'd also do it.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! Link provided in you answer did really help.